# Du und Otto (finden/findet) das gut

Tags: conjugation, list

Ich versuche gerade einen Textgenerator zu erstellen, der wie bei Facebook das Gefallen eines Beitrags ausdrücken soll. Es soll also eine Liste von Datenbankeinträgen in eine sprachliche Aufzählung überführt werden.

Beispiel Facebook:

"Das gefällt Dir, Otto, Anna und 23 weiteren Personen."

Otto und Anna sind in diesem Fall Freunde, werden deshalb namentlich aufgezählt. Es gibt also drei verschiedene Gruppen von Personen:

- man selbst
- Freunde
- andere Nutzer

Nun möchte ich jedoch statt "Gefällt mir" lieber "Finde ich gut" verwenden.

Dadurch ergeben sich ein paar Varianten, je nachdem aus welchen Gruppe die Personen stammen, denen der Beitrag gefällt:

1. Du findest das gut.
2. Otto findet das gut.
3. Otto und Anna finden das gut.
4. Otto und 23 andere Nutzer finden das gut.
5. Otto, Anna und 23 andere Nutzer finden das gut.

Soweit so klar, unsicher bin ich mir aber bei:

6. Du und Otto **(finden/findet)** das gut.
7. Du und 23 andere Nutzer **(finden/findet)** das gut.
8. Du, Otto und 23 andere Nutzer **(finden/findet)** das gut.

Eigentlich müsste es sich ja um die 2. Person Plural handeln, da man durch  das "Du" ja zu der Personengruppe hinzu gezählt wird ("Ihr findet das gut").

Zum Beispiel in Fall 6 hört sich aber "Du und Otto finde **-n** das gut" für mich runder an, also 3. Person.

Comment: Du hast "_Du **findest** das gut "_ vergessen.

Comment: Sollte es nicht in deiner Aufzählung am Anfang heißen "Es gibt also[....] ***einen*** selbst" statt "***man*** selbst"? Also die Objektform von "man"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Form in den Fällen 6-8 lautet, Ihrem Sprachgefühl entsprechend, *finden*. Tatsächlich befinden Sie sich in der 3. Person Plural, nicht der 2. Person Plural.

Grammatisch handelt es sich bei *Du, Otto und 23 andere Nutzer* um ein sog. komplexes Subjekt mit den gereihten Subjektteilen *Du*, *Otto* und *23 andere Nutzer*. Es gilt allgemein die folgende Kongruenzregel für Subjekte mit gereihten Subjektteilen (hier auszugsweise wiedergegeben aus Gallmann in Duden, Die Grammatik, 8. Aufl. 2009, Rn. 1602):

> **Kongruenzregel II für Subjekte mit gereihten Subjektteilen:**
>
> (a) Die Reihung gilt gesamthaft als Plural, das finite Verb steht daher ebenfalls im Plural.
>
> (b) Die 1. Person rangiert vor der 2. Person, und die 2. Person rangiert vor der 3. Person.
>
> **Kongruenzregel III für Subjekte in zusammengezogenen Sätzen mit nur einem finiten Verb:**
>
> Das Verb richtet sich nach dem näher stehenden Subjekt.

Daraus ergibt sich unmittelbar die oben gegebene Antwort.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank!

Comment: Könnten Sie zur Kongruenzregel III ein Beispiel geben?